# javax.servlet.jsp.JspException cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I have a Spring 4 MVC Maven project in Eclipse Mars
I have this error `javax.servlet.jsp.JspException cannot be resolved to a type` in the JSP, even in my Project Facets -> Runtimes I have checked `Apache Tomcat v7.0065`
The error is in Edit time and I can find that type on the project's Java Build Path as M2_REPO/../**javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar**

Comment: Is this message at edit time or run-time? Can you find that type on the project's Java Build Path? Is your JSP explicitly referencing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking at the wrong JAR file for JspException.

I am developing a Spring 4 app in Eclipse with a Maven project, but using an external Tomcat 8 server.  I was receiving the same error message in a JSP in the editor until I created and added a User Library in Eclipse that contained 'jsp-api.jar', which is actually a link in my Ubuntu file system to a file named 'tomcat8-jsp-api.jar'.

Once I added this new user library to my build path and then did a 'Build Project' in Eclipse, the red markers went away.  You may need to refresh the project after building.  Hopefully this at least points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed to add **jsp-api.jar** in your Spring 4 Project